# htaccess simulate subdomain to subdirectory in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to develop a plugin that can write into the WP htaccess file and "simulate" subdomains.

I have a new WP installation with basic htaccess on **example.com**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Is there a way via htaccess that if I go to **about.example.com** I see the page **example.com/about**, without changing the URL (meaning that I still see **about.example.com** in the browser address bar)?

And also, is it possible that if I go to **about.example.com/category1** I see the page **example.com/about/category1**?

I tried using the following code by adding it to the end of the htaccess, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ about [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that using the following rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewirieEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^about.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.about.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/about/$1 [P]
```

What this does is check for the address `about.example.com`, if the condition is met it should redirect to `example.com/about/....` but keeping the original address.

The `[P]` flag causes the request to be handled by `mod_proxy`, and handled via a proxy request.

However, keep in mind that using `mod_proxy` can cause security issues:

> Take care when constructing the target URL of the rule, considering
>   the security impact from allowing the client influence over the set of
>   URLs to which your server will act as a proxy. Ensure that the scheme
>   and hostname part of the URL is either fixed, or does not allow the
>   client undue influence.

Normally using `.htaccess` you cannot go from one domain to another domain keeping the original URL. It can be a security nightmare as mentioned above. However, since this is a subdomain it *should* work.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

**Alternative**

You can use `ProxyPass` - which would be a more secure option. You can find more information on how to use this via the Apache Documentation [via this link.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) But this would need to done on a level higher than `.htaccess`. Through the config files.

I hope this helps.